# Is it possible to do an INSERT in the backend with PHP via Mongolab's RESTful API?

Tags: php, mongodb, rest

I want to send prepared JSON to my PHP script in the backend and then use Mongolab's RESTful API to make an insert. The only example I can find for inserts is with front end AJAX.

**Example code from** [REST API for MongoLab](http://docs.mongolab.com/restapi/#insert-document).

```
POST /databases/{database}/collections/{collection}
Content-Type: application/json
Body: <JSON data>

Example (using jQuery):

$.ajax( { url: "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/my-db/collections/my-coll?apiKey=myAPIKey",
          data: JSON.stringify( { "x" : 1 } ),
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json" } );
```

Unfortuantely, the server admin I work with will not allow me to install the Mongo PHP driver to do this and so I'm forced to go this route.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

**Example of retrieving data**

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/**DATABASE**/collections/**COLLECTION*?q={%22_id%22:{%22$oid%22:%22' . $_GET['id'] . '%22}}&apiKey=**API KEY**');

$obj = json_decode($data);
$obj=$obj[0];
```

Comment: The real question here is that since you are using PHP, which **does** have a native driver implementation, why would you use the REST API in the first place? What is wrong with using the native driver?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot install the MongoDB driver on this particular server. That is why I am forced to use the RESTful API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery example translated into PHP is:

```
<?php
$key        = "my API key";
$db         = "my-database-name";
$collection = "my-collection-name";

$document = array(
    "x" => 1,
    "more" => array("data", "here"),
);

$opts = array(
    "http" => array(
        "method"  => "POST",
        "header"  => "Content-type: application/json",
        "content" => json_encode($document),
    ),
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents("https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/$db/collections/$collection?apiKey=$key", false, $context);

var_dump($result); // Dumps the response document
?>
```